# serial_asyncio: read serial port into a queue and read that queue from main() not working

Tags: python, serial-port

I have a function `do_serial()` that reads from the serial port and adds the data to a queue. I want to process that queue on `main()`.

I have read the serial_asyncio docs and have a basic echo type proof that reads serial data and echoes it back from a single async function. What I cannot get to work is updating the queue and reading the queue from `main()`.

Once I have this working I also want to update another queue on main() and have that get written to the serial port. This way `do_serial()` can run async and process the serial port and `main()` interacts with the queues.

Here is my code:

```
import queue
import asyncio
import serial_asyncio

incoming_serial_queue = queue.Queue()

async def do_serial():
    reader, writer = await serial_asyncio.open_serial_connection(url='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600)
    while True:
        # read serial port
        data = await reader.readline()

        # echo back to serial port for verification
        writer.write(incoming_serial_queue.get)

        # add data to queue
        incoming_serial_queue.put(data)        

async def main():
    while True:
        # read queued data from serial port
        await print(incoming_serial_queue.get())

asyncio.run(do_serial())
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: as for me you need different method then `run()` to start two functions at the same time. `run(do_serial())` may start function `do_serial` and wait for its end - and this way it never runs `main`. If you change order then `run(main())` will wait for end of `main` and it will never run `do_serial`

Comment: you can't use `await` with every function. `await` will not work with starndard `print()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not specialist for `asyncio` but I created some working code - so don't ask why something doesn't work :)

I can't run `serial_asyncio` so I used `datetime` to generate some data for `queue`

You can't use `run()` to start two processes at the same time. `run()` starts one process and waits for its end - so `run(do_serial())` starts function `do_serial` and waits for its end - and this way it never runs `main`. If you change order then `run(main())` will wait for end of `main` and it will never run `do_serial`

So I used `run()` to start one function which use [create_task()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks) for `do_serial()` and `main()`. I had to first create task and later use them with await because in other way it didn't start `main` and I don't know why.

Other problem with `asyncio`: `await` can't work with every function - it will not work with standard `print()`. You would have to create special `print()` for it. Or maybe you have special `print()` from `serial_asyncio` - I don't know.

In both functions I used `asyncio.sleep()` to have some function with `await`

Problem with `queue`: when there is no data in queue then `get()` may block code and it is better to check first if it is not `empty()`

```
import queue
import asyncio
import datetime

incoming_serial_queue = queue.Queue()

async def do_serial():
    print("do serial")
    while True:
        data = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        print('put:', data)

        # add data to queue
        incoming_serial_queue.put(data)

        await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def main():
    print("main")
    while True:
        # read queued data from serial port
        if not incoming_serial_queue.empty():
            data = incoming_serial_queue.get()
            print('get:', data)

        await asyncio.sleep(1) 

async def start():
    print("start")
    #await do_serial()  # doesn't work
    #await main()       # doesn't work

    # I had to create all tasks before running
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(do_serial())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(main())

    # running task
    await task1
    await task2

asyncio.run(start())
```

---

**EDIT:**

I could run two functions using [asyncio.gather()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently)

```
async def start():
    print("start")
    await asyncio.gather(
        do_serial(),
        main(),
    )
```

Rest is the same as in my previous code

```
import queue
import asyncio
import datetime

incoming_serial_queue = queue.Queue()

async def do_serial():
    print("do serial")
    while True:
        data = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        print('put:', data)

        # add data to queue
        incoming_serial_queue.put(data)

        await asyncio.sleep(2)    

async def main():
    print("main")
    while True:
        # read queued data from serial port
        if not incoming_serial_queue.empty():
            data = incoming_serial_queue.get()
            print('get:', data)

        await asyncio.sleep(1) 

async def start():
    print("start")
    await asyncio.gather(
        do_serial(),
        main(),
    )

asyncio.run(start())
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps me understand asyncio more. I am just starting to use it.